# How to click on image link in selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to click behind this link for this image:

[image: want to click behind this link for this image]

HTML:

```
<img src="../images/qi_images/retaileranalytics/Export_XLSX_Normal.png" style="width:32px;height:32px;" onclick="mstrmojo.dom.captureDomEvent('*lK36*kW9AD865CF3BF94D709C845EC84C9867B7*x1*t1659566066908','click', self, event)">
```

I tried to use:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[10]/div[1]/img").click()
```

but does not work please help.

If you right click it you will see a hyperlink popup:

[image: If you right click it you will see a hyperlink popup]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div mstridx="0" class="mstrmojo-ListBox-item mstrmojo-InteractiveText" style="undefined">Hyperlink1</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yeah, I can click on the URL but just can't get the Selenium to click on it. The link will basically take you to a different tab to download.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[src*='Export_XLSX_Normal'][onclick*='captureDomEvent']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@src, 'Export_XLSX_Normal') and contains(@onclick, 'captureDomEvent')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It didn't work for me. I am getting the timeout exception: TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace). If I go without wait, it's the unable to find element message: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: @Mustard From my experience try using CSS_SELECTOR instead of XPATH. Also can try right click>inspect element>copy JSPATH then do driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector('PATH')') (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)